# How to Host Laravel 4.1 App on iPage shared host?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, fatal-error, shared-hosting

I am uploading all my files as they are to the server.

I am installing my database manually on the server.

I am modifying the configuration files. (Not so sure about the 'url' in the app.php file)

Can any one tell me how to run commands on the ipage shared host! In case I want to change some permissions or run the composer commands?

However when I try to access my public directory I get this error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Illuminate\Support\Contracts\ResponsePreparerInterface' not found in /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b2711/ipg.mysite/myapplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 28

Comment: Can you clarify your hosting company- is it www.ipage.com ? Secondly, what hosting plan with them?

Comment: You should probably contact them and ask - many shared hosting plans don't give you CLI access (some do, many don't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPage does not (currently) offer SSH access, so running CLI commands from a CLI seems like a lost cause.

http://www.ipagetraining.com/details/why-no-ssh-access/

In my test cases, I do use the Artisan calls which seem to call the CLI-equivalents (but throwing something like this up on a working site seems.....  very unsafe)

```
  Artisan::call('migrate');
  Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

I've found that running 'php artisan optimize' on your local development box and then uploading the resulting site works fine.  Even though your bootstrap/compiled.php will contain a few references to your local dev box, Laravel seems to work just fine.

If you're concerned about DB migrations, you can always pull the database over locally and run the migrations locally.

Not ideal, I know, but if you don't have extra-sensitive info, it can work.

Comment: `Artisan::call('migrate');  Artisan::call('db:seed');` this codes where do you call it? which file?

Comment: iPage does provide SSH access - just get the correct plan.